# Google Play App Signing enabled does my first apk singing key is now my upload key?

Tags: android, google-play

I have enabled "Google Play App Signing". It shows enabled on the console.

As I am going for new app Google has generated the App signing key.

For upload key I am getting the following message :

```
**Upload certificate**
Your app doesn’t have an upload certificate yet. The certificate you use to sign your first APK will be used as the upload certificate.
```

[image]

I followed Apk signing process as [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk)

So the signing key I use to sign my first apk will become my default upload key?

***Update***

It appears the key we use to sign the first apk will be taken as upload key. The main app signing key is already at play store when I enrolled for `Goole play App Signing`. I created one keystore file [as mentioned here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-apk) Signed my android apk with it. Then uploaded the signed apk to Alpha test release then upload certificates were automatically generated by Google play using my signing key.

**Note:** My question and answer is related with new application enrollment for `Google Play App Signing`. If you have already application signed with app signing key which you manage by yourself and you want to switch to Google Play App singing please [check out this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuaYhnGmeEk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you haven't got an upload key the certificate used to sign your first APK will become your upload key. With Google Play App Signing you can always change your upload key later by contacting Google Play developer support.